# Android: Air gestures using camera

Tags: android, image-processing, gesture

Using the camera of android phone, I want to detect four hand gestures of user:

- Rightward movement of hand in front of camera.
- Leftward movement of hand.
- Upward movement of hand.
- Downward movement of hand.

How can I achieve this? Is there anyway to do it without OpenCV? What are the steps. I'm a beginner in this stuff.